# Changing environment in unity3D- best approach?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

I have several environments in my VR scene - 5 rooms, the user is going through, during the simulation.

My friend suggested I use enable/disabled to "open/close" the rooms, having all the rooms in one scene while only one is enabled at a time.

I wonder if making each room into a scene is a better and cleaner approach.

What factors should be considered when choosing?

What would you do?

Comment: The answers you get for this will be largely opinion based, rather than a concrete "best" solution.

Comment: ...Even then the concrete "best" solution might depend on factors you haven't supplied and vary from project to project.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on such factors?

Comment: Factors like: how big each room is (memory footprint). What device the game will be running on (hardware limitations). Possibly others that are hard to predict, like whether or not you need to transfer information about something as the player moves from room to room.

Comment: Ok, yeah the player needs to transfer some information, like the things he collects in each room to be displayed on a canvas, and each room is really small. It's VR, on a stand alone. I have one navmesh for all the rooms...I start to think that maybe enable/disable is a lest costly approach here... as having different scenes would mean duplicating many components shared by all rooms.